# Получить вероятности пренадлежности к кластерам k-means

Tags: python, машинное-обучение

Мне нужно получить для каждого объекта вероятность принадлежности его к каждому из кластеров. Для k-means это можно сделать, посчитав расстояние каждого объекта до центра каждого кластера. Наиболее удаленная точка от кластера принадлежит ему с почти нулевой вероятностью, наиболее приближенная, с вероятностью 1.

Проблема заключается в том, что линейный функции (MinMaxScaler, например) дают результат, где у объектов почти везде почти одинаковая вероятность принадлежности к каждому из классов. (Изначальные данные - это матрица `8000х5000`).

Как подобрать нелинейность, которая давала бы единицу в ближайшей точке, скажем, 0.5 в дальней точке, принадлежащей кластеру, а потом начинала резко падать? Как это дело автоматизировать на Python (Получается около 25 кластеров).

Comment: Получил ответ по [ссылке](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/14435/how-to-get-the-probability-of-belonging-to-clusters-for-k-means).

Answer (score -1):

Возможно, для этого стоит использовать логистическую функцию вида:

```
sigma(x) = 1/(1+exp(-x))
```